# Change database after scaffolding to local database

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, scaffolding, localdb, mdf

I created the scaffolded project according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) tutorial

There is written

```
For local development, the ASP.NET Core configuration system reads the connection string from the appsettings.json file.
```

What is the correct procedure to change this local database (*.mdf file) to "global" database (e.g. MSSQL server installed on the network)?

Comment: By global to you mean a remote one not in the same pc you are developing?

Comment: @AntoniosKatopodis not in the same pc. In opposite to the local database file (mdf extension). e.g. database in MSSQL Server or Mysql or PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1):

Scaffolding has nothing to do with whether the database is local or remote, assuming of course that they share the same schema. If the remote database schema is different, you need only rescaffold, which is what you will need to do for any change of schema.

All you really have is a connection string. The connection string just happens to point to a local database. To point at a remote database, you simply change the connection string to the information for that remote database. Local or remote means nothing as far as your app is concerned; it's just connecting to whatever you told it to connect to.

By default, the connection string exists in `appsettings.json`. To change it, you can either directly change it in `appsettings.json` or override it using another config source such as environment-specific JSON (i.e. `appsettings.Production.json`), environment variables, command-line arguments, etc.

However, a connection string is going to contain sensitive information (user/pass), and it's therefore a secret. As such, you should not store any real database information in something like JSON, which is not encrypted and will be committed to source control. Instead, you should use a config source external to your app code (e.g. environment variables on the server) and preferably something where data is encrypted at rest (e.g. Azure Key Vault). In development, you can also use user secrets. It's just another JSON source, so it's still not encrypted. However, it's stored outside your project, and therefore will at least not end up in your source control.

Comment: So it means that I will change my connection string and then run migration and the database will be created from the model according to where the connection string points? Could you make a general example (format) of the connection string for MS SQL server?

Comment: If you're scaffolding your database, that means you have an existing database, in which case you should not be generating migrations. If you need to change the database schema, you make that change at the database manually or via a SQL script, and then you rescaffold your entity classes/context from the existing database afterwards.

Comment: The default connection string (local) is already in the format for SQL Server. LocalDB is a SQL Server Express instance.

Comment: I have a model from which the scaffolder created a database (mdf file) and now I'd like to create the same tables that are in mdf file in MS SQL server.